# Minimal dimension of maximal abelian subalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semi-simple finite dimensional  Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$.
Is it true that
$$
\dim \mathfrak h \ge \mathop{rank} \mathfrak g 
$$
for **any** maximal   abelian subalgebra $\mathfrak h \subset \mathfrak g$ ? Here by maximal I mean that $\mathfrak h$ is not properly contained in any other abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the dimension is exactly the rank.  The wording "bounded from below" seems confusing here, so I'll have to double-check.

Comment: I think that "bounded from below" simply means $\dim \mathfrak{h} \geq \mathrm{rank} \mathfrak{g}$.  I'm not sure whether it matters that we are over $\mathbb{C}$ here.  Certainly there are (noncompact) real forms of semisimple Lie algebras with maximal abelian subalgebras of dimension greater than the rank.  A typical example is $\mathfrak{so}(1,2n-1)$, which has rank $n$, but admits a maximal abelian subalgebra of dimension $2n-2$.

Comment: In fact, since the rank is the dimension of any Cartan subalgebra and Cartan subalgebras are maximally abelian *and* self-normalising, doesn't this show that the answer is yes?

Comment: @José: If maximal means not contained in any larger abelian algebra there could be ones of smaller dimension.

Comment: Dear Jos\'e: Results about Cartan subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras don't seem to formally imply a whole lot about the nature of commutative Lie subalgebras consisting entirely of nilpotent elements, so some further arguments seem necessary. (One can reduce to the case when all elements of $\mathfrak{h}$ are nilpotent in $\mathfrak{g}$, for whatever that's worth...maybe very little.)

Comment: Dear Brian and Torsten: thanks, I now understand the question better.  Indeed, I agree that the results about Cartans are not that helpful.
Please ignore my second comment!  (I would delete it, but then this would orphan your own comments.)


Comment: I misread the question, for which the answer is probably yes.   Any such subalgebra lies in a Borel subalgebra, where the main difficulty is to sort out the abelian subalgebras of the nilradical.    The *ideals* of this type in a Borel have been most intensively studied (by Peterson, Panyushev, and others).   Older work by Zassenhaus and his collaborators described arbitrary maximal abelian subalgebras mainly in classical types, I think, but anyway I'm not sure how to give a precise answer to the general question.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Zassenhaus et al. have examples when the dimension of maximal abelian sub is bigger than the rank. I don't think it ever gets smalles in their calculations...

Comment: To add one more comment (while subtracting my first offhand one), the complex simple Lie algebra of type `$G_2$` suggests how natural examples arise with dimension `$>2$`:
If `$\alpha$`/`$\beta$` are the short/long simple roots, root vectors belonging to `$\alpha, 3\alpha+\beta, 3\alpha+2\beta$` span a 3-dimensional abelian ideal in a Borel subalgebra.   (The highest root always gives a vector in the center of the nilradical.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer to my question is no. A search at Mathscinet revealed the following:

> Gerstenhaber conjectured in [Ann. of
>   Math. (2) 73 (1961), 324--348;
>   MR0132079 (24 #A1926)] that a maximal
>   commutative subalgebra of the
>   associative ring of $n\times n$
>   matrices $M_n(k)$ always has dimension
>   $\ge n$, and proved this is the case
>   for subalgebras generated by two
>   elements.
>
> The conjecture was disproved by 
>   Courter in [Duke Math. J. 32 (1965),
>   225--232; MR0174583 (30 #4784)], by
>   constructing a maximal commutative
>   subalgebra of $M_{14}(k)$ having
>   dimension $13$. Tensor powers give further examples of dimension $13^m$ in $M_{14^m}(k)$.
>
> Gustafson [J. Algebra 42 (1976), no.
>   2, 557--563; MR0422341 (54 #10331)]
>   proved the lower bound $\ge n^{2/3}$
>   for arbitrary maximal commutative
>   subalgebras of $M_n(k)$.
>
> More recently, Laffey [Linear Algebra
>   Appl. 71 (1985), 199--212; MR0813045
>   (87a:15025)] improved the lower bound
>   to $(2n)^{2/3}$ and exhibited
>   infinitely many maximal commutative
>   subalgebras of $M_n(k)$ having
>   dimension $3n^{2/3} - 4$.

I haven't looked at the papers mentioned above yet but they seem to imply that there are
maximal abelian Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,k)$ ( or  $\mathfrak{sl}(n,k)$ )
having dimension smaller than $n-1$.

Indeed, start with a maximal commutative subalgebra $H \subset M_n(k)$. Since, it is commutative the Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is trivial over it. Therefore it gives rise
to an abelian subalgebra $\mathfrak h \subset \mathfrak{gl}(n,k)$ which must be maximal. Otherwise the associative subalgebra generated by any abelian Lie subalgebra containing it would be a commutative subalgebra of $M_n(k)$ strictly containg $H$.

---

I finally took a look at the papers mentioned above. 
Courter's example  is the subalgebra of $M_{14}(k)$
generated by the Identity and elements of the form
$$ 
\left(
  \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
    0&0&a&0&b&0&c&e&0&f&0&g&m&n\\
    0&0&0&a&0&b&d&0&e&0&f&h&p&q\\
     & & & & & & & & & & & &c&0\\
     & & & & & & & & & & & &d&0\\
     & & & & & & & & & & & &0&c\\
     & & & & & & & & & & & &0&d\\
     & & & & & & & & & & & &a&b\\
     & & & & & & & & & & & &g&0\\     
     & & & & & &0 & & & & & &h&0\\     
     & & & & & & & & & & & &0&g\\     
     & & & & & & & & & & & &0&h\\     
     & & & & & & & & & & & &e&f\\     
     & & & & & & & & & & & &0&0\\
     & & & & & & & & & & & &0&0
  \end{array}
\right)
$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,m,n,p,q \in k$ are arbitrary. These very same elements
generate a maximal abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(14,k)$ of dimension $12$ as  I, or rather my computer,  checked.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, since these results have all been refereed and I am just some guy on the internet, I hope I can find my mistake!  It will have to wait til tomorrow, though.

Comment: I'm skeptical about the sketch above, notably the final statement.   Details?   Associative and Lie subalgebras of the matrix algebra need to be compared more carefully.   I still haven't pinned down a literature reference for the original question, but have some recollection that the rank is known to be least dimension of a maximal abelian Lie subalgebra.   It may be useful to look at some of the older papers by Zassenhaus et al.   In any case, the question has certainly come up in the past.

Comment: @jvp:  See my expanded answer concerning the problem I have with your approach.   Study of the full matrix algebra, or general linear Lie algebra, isn't directly relevant for the study of semisimple Lie algebras.

Comment: @jim I don't see what your worry can be. The space jvp presents is easily seen to be closed under multiplication. So it is both a subalgebra and a sub-Lie-algebra of $sl_{14}$. If you want algebras to have units, then the span of it and the identity is a subalgebra of $gl_{14}$. I have not checked the computation that this is abelian and maximal, but if that computation is right, it should be right both in the sense of Lie algebras and associative algebras.

Comment: @David: I can't access the Coulter paper just now and shouldn't prolong the discussion.   But I can't yet see how the *maximality* was proved.   It would reassure me to know that the proof had been checked rigorously over the years, since such ad hoc constructions are always tricky with or without computers and also since the whole area of study seems to lack deeper theory.  (I'm placing no bets, one way or the other, just yet.)

Comment: Well, the brute force way to do it is to compute the rank of a system of $12 \times 14 \times 14$ linear equations in $14^2$ variables. I assume this is what jvp has done; I agree that it would take some effort.

Comment: @David. That's exactly what I've done. It takes less than 15 seconds in my machine. 

Answer (score 4):

[Edited again.  This argument has a fatal flaw (and the conclusion is probably false; see jvp's answer).  Lessons: random maximal abelian subalgebras might be pretty weird, self-normalizing is a much nicer condition; check mathscinet more carefully; don't abuse Jordan normal form, it might bite back.]

There is a mistake below: it is *not* true that the kernel of a generic linear combination of commuting nilpotent matrices is the intersection of the kernels.  For a counterexample, take x to be a 4 by 4 matrix which is the direct sum of two 2 by 2 Jordan blocks, and take y to have the same block diagonal entries, and a 2 by 2 identity matrix in its upper right hand corner.  Then the kernel of $ax+by$ is only contained in the kernel of x when b=0.  I sincerely hope I have never assigned this "fact" as a homework problem...

The rest is preserved for your amusement.

Here goes again:

The answer is yes.  The proof rests on 2 facts:

(1) in a semisimple Lie algebra of rank $n$, the minimal dimension of the centralizer $C(x)$ of an element $x$ is $n$, and

(2) in *any* Lie algebra (say over $\mathbb{C}$, though surely this works in greater generality) every maximal abelian subalgebra is the centralizer of one of its elements.

For (1):

The set $$C=\{(x,y) \in \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \ | \ [x,y]=0\}$$ is a subvariety of $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g}$ whose fiber over $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ is the centralizer $C(x)$ of $x$ in $\mathfrak{g}$.  For generic (regular semisimple) $x$ the dimension of $C(x)$ is $n=\text{rank}(\mathfrak{g})$.  It follows that the dimension of $C(x)$ is always at least $n$.

For (2):

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a maximal abelian subalgebra.  If $x_1,...,x_m$ are a basis of $\mathfrak{h}$ and $z \in \bigcap_{i=1}^m C(x_i)$ then $[z,\mathfrak{h}]=0$ and hence $z \in \mathfrak{h}$ by maximality of $\mathfrak{h}$.  It follows that
$$\mathfrak{h}=\bigcap_{i=1}^m C(x_i).$$

Now we claim that the intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^m C(x_i)$ is the centralizer of a generic linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i$.  It suffices to show that there exist $a_1,\dots,a_m \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $$\bigcap_{i=1}^m C(x_i)=C(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i).$$  By induction on $m$ we may assume $m=2$.  Since $C(x)=\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{ad}(x))$ we have reduced to the following linear algebra problem: let $x$ and $y$ be commuting matrices with complex entries.  Then for generic $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ the kernel of $ax+by$ is the intersection of the kernels of $x$ and $y$.

Let $x=x_s+x_n$ be the decomposition of $x$ into commuting semisimple and nilpotent parts, and likewise write $y=y_s+y_n$.  Then since $x$ and $y$ commute $ax+by=a(x_s+y_s)+b(x_n+y_n)$ is the decomposition of $ax+by$ into commuting nilpotent and semisimple parts.  Furthermore $\mathrm{ker}(x)=\mathrm{ker}(x_s) \cap \mathrm{ker}(x_n)$, so we may assume that $x$ and $y$ are either both semisimple or both nilpotent.

If $x$ and $y$ are both semisimple (and commuting) then it's easy to see that the kernel of $ax+by$ is the intersection of the kernels of $x$ and $y$ for generic $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

In the remaining case $x$ and $y$ are both nilpotent, and since they commute we may choose a basis such that $x$ is in Jordan form and $y$ is (strictly) upper triangular.  It follows that as long as $a+bc \neq 0$ for all superdiagonal entries $c$ of $y$, we have $\mathrm{ker}(ax+by) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(x)$.  Symmetrically, $\mathrm{ker}(ax+by) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(y)$ for generic $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, done.

[Remark: I'm pretty sure I've assigned the proof of this last fact (that the kernel of a generic linear combination $ax+by$ is the intersection of the kernels if $x$ and $y$ commute) as a homework problem at some point, which is why I was originally so cavalier.  But I have to admit I can't find it written down somewhere so maybe I'm imagining things.  Can anyone provide a reference?]

Comment: The intersection of centralisers does not have to be abelian. Thus it is not clear why it is equal to $h$.

Comment: Bugs: whether or not it is abelian is irrelevant: let $z$ be in this intersection.  Then $[z,\mathfrak{h}]=0$ so $\mathfrak{h}+\mathbb{C} z$ is abelian, and hence $z \in \mathfrak{h}$ by maximality.

Comment: Sheik: i do not see why the intersection of centralizers is the centralizer of a linear combination. 

Comment: This argument doesn't work. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be `$\mathfrak{sl}_{2n}$` and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be the $n^2$ dimensional subspace of matrices which are $0$ except in the upper right $n \times n$ submatrix. So $\mathfrak{h}$ is abelian. For any $x \in \mathfrak{h}$, we have $x^2=0$, so the Jordan form of $x$ is a direct sum of `$\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$'s` and $(0)$'s. As the reader can work out, the centralizer of such a matrix always has dimension at least $2n^2-1$.

Comment: David: urgh, thanks for pointing that out.  I was just about to get to 4 by 4 examples.

Comment: Wait a sec: David, your example shows this: an abelian subalgebra might not be the centralizer of one of its elements.  But your subalgebra is not maximal.  In any case, I agree the argument I gave above has a gap, but I still think it's right (modulo proving the last assertion)...

Comment: ...to really convince me that I'm wrong you can do the following: find two commuting matrices $x$ and $y$ such that the kernel of a generic linear combination $ax+by$ is strictly bigger than the intersection of the kernels.  Otherwise the argument I gave works (and I think I have a proof of the last fact but it's too long to fit in this comment box and I have to make pancakes before my kids die of hunger).

Comment: David: ok, I just edited to address the last point.  Do you agree now?

Comment: Nice! So the point is that, for any abelian $\mathfrak{h}$, we have $C(\mathfrak{h}) = C(x)$ for a generic $x$ in $\mathfrak{h}$. When $\mathfrak{h}$ is maximal, this shows that $\mathfrak{h} = C(x)$.

Comment: Rather, for abelian $\mathfrak{h}$, $\mathfrak{h}$ is maximal abelian iff it is the centralizer of one of its elements.

Comment: David, er... yes, I misread $C(\mathfrak{h})$ as $\mathfrak{h}$ for some reason.  sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Some of my previous comments were unfortunately too casual and unfocused, but I still suspect that the answer to the original question is yes.   At the same time, I can't document precisely enough what is known about the *exceptional* simple Lie algebras over $\mathbb{C}$.    I'm not aware of any unified Lie-theoretic arguments, in any case.

For the *classical* simple types (including the trace zero matrices?), the older papers are sometimes hard to read but have many concrete details.   The main tool used is linear algebra, inspired in part by a long tradition in the study of (associative) matrix algebras going back to Schur, Kravchuk, and Mal'cev.  In particular, there is a series of papers by Patera, Winternitz, and Zassenhaus on classical real or complex Lie algebras, some published in the journal *Linear Algebra and its Applications* which is in our university library but not available online to us.   One article I can access online is typical:

MR713527 (84i:17006) 17B05 (22E10),
Patera, J. (3-MTRL-R); Winternitz, P. (3-MTRL-R); Zassenhaus, H. (1-OHS),
Maximal abelian subalgebras of real and complex symplectic Lie algebras.
J. Math. Phys. 24 (1983), no. 8, 1973–1985.

Their emphasis is on classifying the maximal ones up to conjugacy under the adjoint group, with emphasis on those like the Cartan subalgebras and the contrasting ones consisting of nilpotent matrices.   Dimension considerations seem secondary.    But as far as I can see, over $\mathbb{C}$ they always find that the minimum dimension of a maximal abelian subalgebra is equal to the rank, while the maximum dimension tends to be larger.

Concerning jvp's own references to work of Gerstenhaber and others on the full matrix algebra, it has to be kept in mind that the simple linear Lie algebras in question aren't usually closed under ordinary matrix multiplication.   This makes comparisons of commutative subalgebras and abelian Lie algebras tricky, I think.   However, I haven't gone far enough into the literature to feel confident about exactly what is true.    It would help to have a modern survey of the entire problem area for both matrix algebras and semisimple Lie algebras.

ADDED: Though I haven't yet seen the Courter paper or his pre-computer proof method, the description here and jvp's reported computer verification suggests that for type A this Lie subalgebra of the special linear algebra consisting of nilpotent upper triangular matrices is maximal and of dimension less than the rank.   On the other hand, the published results for classical simple Lie algebras suggest that the rank is a lower bound in those types.   I'm uncertain how much is known about the exceptional types, so I guess I'd emphasize the last line of my earlier answer and the related question whether a Lie-theoretic understanding of the problem exists (beyond linear algebra).    But I'm happy to drop my original guess that the rank is always the minimum dimension if Courter's proof says otherwise.

Comment: @Jim. Thanks for the comments. Most of the arguments I've found in the literature are commutative algebra together with clever linear algebra. I agree with you that a modern survey of the problem area would very welcome. I am even tempted to try my hand at it, but I doubt I will have time in a near future. 